# Artifactory: Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed

Tags: postgresql, registry, artifactory, amazon-eks

Giving you some background- We have up and running Jfrog to EKS, however due some other issue the whole EKS cluster become unstable and also noticed Jfrog prod is down. We clean EKS and make it stable, then we restarted the Artifactory pod, but it's showing running but with 3/4 container. Please note: We are using external postgress (RDS). We checked the log, the Artifactory log is showing like below-

Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused [access_client] 2020-04-21T17:34:04.104Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [23242344354354] [join_executor.go:148 ] [main ] - Cluster join: Retry 10: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Could not parse error from service registry, status code: 404, raw body: HTTP Status 404 – Not Foundh1.

Could you please help here.